# python catching "all other error" type example case

Tags: python, error-handling

In the code below when I ran it it suppose to catch all error with "except Exception as error:" return " Not possible" but thats
not the case when I set mystery_value = a it gives me a NameError. I don't understand this could someone help explain? Thanks.

```
mystery_value = a

try:
    print(10/mystery_value)
except ZeroDivisionError as error:
    print("Can't divide by zero")
except Exception as error:
    print("Not possible")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because the error occurs before the try except block. it occurs at the first line because *a* doesn't refer to anything and it doesn't run reach the try except. if you replaced a with 'a' the exception would work.

```
mystery_value = 'a' # replace a with 'a'

try:
    print(10/mystery_value)
except ZeroDivisionError as error:
    print("Can't divide by zero")
except Exception as error:
    print("Not possible")
```

output

```
Not possible
```